# java array as value in map

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I would like to check if a given array (with int[]'s as values) contains a specific int[].

I have tried this already.

```
private static final int[][] neighbours = {
        {-1, 0}, {-1, +1},
        {0, -1}, {0, +1},
        {+1, -1}, {+1, 0}};
```

---

```
    List<int[]> drawAt = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int[] tilePos : imageCoordMap.values()) {
        for (int[] neighbour : neighbours) {

            int[] wtf = {tilePos[0] + neighbour[0], tilePos[1] + neighbour[1]};

            if (imageCoordMap.containsValue(wtf)) {
                drawAt.add(wtf);
            }
        }

    }
```

the values of the imageCoordMap map contains coordinates x and y in form of an array.

The problem with my code is for some reason the imageCoordMap.containsValue(wtf) always returns true, even if it shouldn't and I can't figure out why. I already tried debugging but with no success

Comment: What is imageCoordMap?

Comment: it is a map i created containing on the one side an image and on the other side the coordinate of that image on a grid i drew. Now I would like to check if the value of that map contains the int[] array: int[] wtf = {tilePos[0] + neighbour[0], tilePos[1] + neighbour[1]};. But for some reason this always returns true even if it shouldn't

Comment: How did you debug? Can you output the values of imageCoordMap and then give an example where it returns true, but shouldn't?

Comment: I think what Natecat is trying to get at is if imageCoordMap is not the same object type as wtf, you are going to run into problems.

Comment: no it's an int it looks like this private Map<Image, int[]> imageCoordMap = new HashMap<>();

Comment: You're assuming that `int[]` overrides `equals`. It doesn't.

Comment: the values of the imageCoordMap change in game (it's a game i am creating). when adding a pion de Map get's updated with a new coordinate, else when deleting a pion a coordinate is deleted

Comment: I don't really get it? I am assuming that containsValue(); should just check if my map contains a given value regardless of it being an int[] or String

Comment: containsValue() isn't made for int[]s, it's made for any object you can pass into it. It assumes that the object you're passing into it has a meaningful .equals method.

Comment: Oh so I will have to override the equals method for this to work?

Comment: In int[] you would, but I'm assuming you don't want to write a wrapper class. A better solution would to use imageCoordMap.values() and manually check using something like Arrays.equals()

Comment: replacing the containsValue with `if (Arrays.equals(wtf, tilePos)){

                    drawAt.add(wtf);

                }` gives me the same result

Comment: That does a completely different thing then it looks like you intended to do with the code in the OP

Comment: I know this was just to test if the Arrays.equals did what it should do. because now even if the two ints aren't equal the if returns true

Comment: print out the arrays inside the if statement, I wanna see the output, because that doesn't make sense

Comment: Are you allowed to use an ArrayList for this assignment? Because this could make things a little cleaner. ArrayLists are way more flexible than []s

Comment: I am oh and you were right the Array.equals works correctly but how am I supposed to use it to check if the map contains an array?

Comment: Unnecessary and more resource heavy. int[]s work better here because he is only using them as part of an int[][], and multi-dimensional arrays are much more readable than multi-dimensional lists.

Comment: instanceof will do that for you. array instanceof new int []

Comment: The simplest solution is to loop through the values  list and check for equality on each of the arrays.

Comment: isn't that incredibly unefficient?

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java It's actually how it does it already

Comment: Ok your way works great but problem is i also need it to do something when my given int is not in the map. Using the "!" Operator wouldn't work in this case

Comment: Use a boolean outside the scope of the loop. Make it true if you find the array is contained, and then have an if statement outside the loop that is !boolean

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to code the contains method yourself:

```
static boolean contains(int[][] array, int[] value) {
    for (int[] element : array) {
        if (Arrays.equals(element, value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And dont worry its not going to be inefficient. Java's contains and equals methods also loop. You just dont see it.